# window.onbeforeunload in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to prevent frame busting via a chrome extension. In particular, I want to use a method referenced in this paper (https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/framebust.pdf), but I don't have access to the html page directly. Is there a way to use chrome extension to do the equivalent of windows.onbeforeunload below? I read https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest, but not sure if any of those are applicable in this situation.

Frame busting code in www.example.com

```
if (parent.location != self.location) {
    parent.location = self.location ;
}
```

What I want the chrome extension to do is the equivalent of the below

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return ”Asking the user nicely”;
}
</script>

<iframe src = ”http://www.example.com”>
```

Comment: If you use a chrome extension, then you can have access to the page directly if you are using content scripts

Comment: Thanks Pavlo - I think that's the way to go as well after reading about content scripts.

Comment: onbeforeunload no longer displays custom messages in modern browsers.